# Why does the openssh-server not use GCM by default?

Tags: aes, openssh

Well the question is as simple as that . Because I recently noticed that the openssh-server uses AES-CTR for the symmetric encryption and I wondered why ? 
From what I heared AES-CTR is a block cipher mode that can be run in parallel , but GCM has a built in integrity check and is a stream cipher mode . 
So why does HTTPS use GCM in almost any scenarios and SSH not ?

Comment: CTR and GCM are both modes that turn a block cipher into a stream cipher. Note that CTR, as used by OpenSSH, is still authenticated because of its use of HMAC. CTR with HMAC is likely to be compatible with a wider range of clients than GCM.